# Error when exporting a variable in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I want to export a variable. but this happens

**1st file**

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');


class testCommand extends commando.Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client,{
            name: 'test',
            group: 'music',
            memberName: 'test',
            description: 'test',
        });

    }

    async run(message, args) {

        var Testo = 'hello'

    }

}

module.exports.Testo = Testo;
module.exports = testCommand;
```

**2nd file**

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
var Testotest = require('./test.js')


class pauseCommand extends commando.Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client,{
            name: 'pause',
            group: 'music',
            memberName: 'pause',
            description: 'Pause music',
        });

    }


    async run(message, args) {

        message.channel.send(Testotest.Testo())

    }

}

module.exports = pauseCommand;
```

**Error**

```
ReferenceError: Testo is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/andrew/Desktop/NullBot_/commands/music/test.js:27:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/andrew/Desktop/NullBot_/commands/music/pause.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
```

Why does it give an error?

Comment: looks like you are instantly overriding exports.testo, try changing the last export line to something along these lines `module.exports.testCommand = testCommand;`

Answer (score 1):

You define `Testo` in method `run`
if you run method `run` `Testo = 'hello'`, but you define `class testCommand`, so `Testo` is `undefined`, you shold run method `run` one time to define `Testo`.

This code

```
module.exports.Testo = Testo;
```

set `module.exports = {Testo: Testo}`

but you use

```
module.exports = testCommand;
```

set `module.exports = testCommand`

When you call `Testotest.Testo` is `testCommand.Testo` (undefined)

change your code in 1st file:

```
module.exports = testCommand;
module.exports.Testo = Testo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mayby gaonna wanna to use `module.exports` in this way.

```
module.exports = {
    key1: val1,
    key2: val2
}
```

So, your code `module.exports.Testo = Testo; module.exports = testCommand;` can use this format, and It will not throw errors.

Comment: what if I need to export a function that has to be run but I also need the function in a variable to be exported to be used in another file?

Comment: You can declear `testCommand.Testo = Testo`, and `module.exports = testCommand;`

Answer (score 0):

You have this file defined, I understand is test.js:

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');


class testCommand extends commando.Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client,{
            name: 'test',
            group: 'music',
            memberName: 'test',
            description: 'test',
        });

    }

    async run(message, args) {
      var Testo = 'hello'
    }
}

// Testo is not defined because is under method run
module.exports.Testo = Testo;
module.exports = testCommand;
```

You can see the problem better now because is well indented. This module is loading sync and you are exporting Testo following sync way, so, the error is expected.
If you want to fix this you need to define "var Testo" outside of "run" method or make this module async.

Regards

Comment: so is there a way to export a variable in a ‘run’ function?

Comment: without putting the module.exports inside the run function